# Descargar Archivo excel del Servidor

Tags: c#, html, ajax, excel, servidor

Para descargar un archivo de excel, Este es mi codigo pero solo me manda un alert con un "OK", uso un generic Handler.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=Reporte de Extensiones.xlsx");
        response.TransmitFile(context.Server.MapPath("/Files/Reporte de Extensiones.xlsx"));
        response.End();
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Disculpa, es por Ajax? si es así aquí esta la respuesta. Estuve en las mismas una vez xd,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670209/download-excel-file-via-ajax-mvc